# insert multiple columns table laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

i was wondering how can i insert  an array of data into one table by using of 2 array like this in laravel model

```
   $attributes  =array('title','description'); 
   $options =array('test','blahblahblah');
```

the table would be like

title test

description blahblahblah

so far i reach to this

```
 $values = array(
    array($attributes => $options),
    );
```

but it says

Illegal array key type array less
Arrays and objects can not be used as array keys.

any way i try has different error
but the most of the errors is illegal offset type
do you have any suggestion?

Comment: use json column in mysql so u can store value in array

Comment: how can i implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine both arrays with [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). It will take an array for the keys and one array for the values.

```
$attributes = array('title', 'description');
$options = array('test', 'blahblahblah');

$values = array_combine($attributes, $options);
```

Result:

```
array:2 [▼
  "title" => "test"
  "description" => "blahblahblah"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. First you have to combine array as following:

   ```
   $tableFields = array('title', 'description');
   $fieldValues = array('test', 'blahblahblah');
   $newArr = array_combine($tableFields, $fieldValues);
   ```

   Output :

   ```
   array:2 [▼
               "title" => "test"
               "description" => "blahblahblah"
           ]
   ```
2. Then insert into table as following:

   ```
   DB::table('table_name')->insert($newArr);
   ```